# Eigenvalues in commutative diagram

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagram-chasing

Let $K$ be a field.
Suppose, we have linear maps $f: K^n \mapsto K^n$, $g: K^m \mapsto K^m$ and $h: K^n \mapsto K^m$ such that $h$ is surjective and $h \circ f = g\circ h$. Then every eigenvalue of $g$ is also an eigenvalue of $f$.

I tried a few things but wasn't successful.

Comment: "I tried a few things" - what did you try? Since you've made some attempts at it, please include your efforts

Comment: @Lorago currently Iam on my phone, so I will give you only a rough sketch: first I tried to prove the result directly, but after some time with no results I considered contradiction. For an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $g$, I assumed that $\alpha(x) = f(x)- \lambda x$ was an isomorphism and tried to contradict this assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda \in K$. We want to prove that if $g-\lambda \text{id}$ is not surjective, then $f-\lambda \text{id}$ is not surjective.

Equivalently; if $f-\lambda \text{id}$ is surjective, then so is $g-\lambda \text{id}$.

Indeed, this follows from
$$
h(f-\lambda \text{id}) = hf-\lambda h = gh-\lambda h = (g-\lambda \text{id})h
$$
and the fact that for two functions $A \stackrel k \to B \stackrel l \to C$; if $lk$ is surjective, then so is $l$.